# TypeError: UMat() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, opencv

I try to create a new cv UMat in python. The documentation says there are folloing possibilities for the constructor's parameters:

```
§ UMat() [4/19]
cv::UMat::UMat  (   int     rows,
int     cols,
int     type,
const Scalar &  s,
UMatUsageFlags  usageFlags = USAGE_DEFAULT 
)       
Python:
<UMat object>   =   cv.UMat(    [, usageFlags]  )
<UMat object>   =   cv.UMat(    rows, cols, type[, usageFlags]  )
<UMat object>   =   cv.UMat(    size, type[, usageFlags]    )
<UMat object>   =   cv.UMat(    rows, cols, type, s[, usageFlags]   )
<UMat object>   =   cv.UMat(    size, type, s[, usageFlags] )
<UMat object>   =   cv.UMat(    m   )
<UMat object>   =   cv.UMat(    m, rowRange[, colRange] )
<UMat object>   =   cv.UMat(    m, roi  )
<UMat object>   =   cv.UMat(    m, ranges   )
```

I used the `rows`, `cols` and `type` as parameters. This throws a `TypeError: UMat() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)`

Here's the code:

```
width = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
...
array255 = cv2.UMat(height, width, cv2.CV_8UC1)
```

Comment: I bet `width` and `height` hold floating point values. With integers it works, floats reproduce your problem.

Comment: which version of OpenCV are you using? I use 3.4.1 and I don't get any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that [`VideoCapture::get`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#aa6480e6972ef4c00d74814ec841a2939) returns a floating point value. You pass this directly to a [constructor which takes integers](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d7/d45/classcv_1_1UMat.html#add0dc0febd6a7b6a7a79a85d41bb17f2).

Unfortunately the data type of the arguments is used by the Python wrappers to select which of the multiple overloads of the constructor to call. (The error messages when this fails tend to be rather confusing)

To demonstrate (OpenCV 4.0):

```
>>> cv2.UMat(10.0, 12.0,  cv2.CV_8UC1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: UMat() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

>>> cv2.UMat(10, 12,  cv2.CV_8UC1)
<UMat 000000000573DC50>
```

In OpenCV 3.4.x the error message is slightly different, but the outcome is the same:

```
>>> cv2.UMat(10.0, 12.0,  cv2.CV_8UC1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: no matching UMat constructor found/supported

>>> cv2.UMat(10, 12,  cv2.CV_8UC1)
[ INFO:0] Initialize OpenCL runtime...
<cv2.UMat object at 0x0506FA90>
```

The fix is simple, just cast `width` and `height` to integers.

```
width = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)

array255 = cv2.UMat(int(height), int(width), cv2.CV_8UC1)
```